# in ionic...How to declare, assign and call url from .state in app.js?

Tags: url, ionic-framework

How to declare, assign and call url from .state in app.js?

For example : url:/sample

url is sample but where i declare this sample that is url

any body can explain this.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: you are going to need to provide a bit more information here if you are looking for assistance

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of a `state` could look as follows:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic'])  
 .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('page1', {
            url: "/page1",
            templateUrl: "page1.html"
            }
        })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/page1");
});
```

The `page1.html` would be a file which is located in the same directory as your `index.html`, namely `www`.